# Not able to use the nifi view functionality. It states that the "nifi-content-viewer" is not found

Tags: apache-nifi

I am not able to use the nifi view functionality. It states that the "nifi-content-viewer" is not found.

In order to replicate this simply go into any of the processors.

1) Right click a connection that has flowfile content > Select "List queue":

2) Select "View Details" on any item (far left icon) > Ensure "Details" tab is selected > Select "View" button:

3) Download option is working fine

Also,NiFi is clustered.

I am not using any proxy.  Apache version is 2.4.
The entry showing in the nifi.properties:

> nifi.content.viewer.url=/nifi-content-viewer/

Comment: What version of Apache NiFi are you using? Are you running behind a proxy? What is the value of nifi.content.viewer.url in your nifi.properties?

Comment: Hi Matt,

No proxy is using and the apache version is 2.4.
====
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
====

The entry showing in the nifi.properties is:

#####
nifi.content.viewer.url=/nifi-content-viewer/
#####

Comment: What is the file size you try to view and `mime.type` property value on this file?

Comment: There is no value given to mime.type